# SQL exception from java netbeans, can't seem to find the cause

Tags: java, netbeans, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update a database in MySql workbench from java netbeans, and can't seem to find the root cause for this exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
```

The numbers seem to match... but the index is always out of range
Here's my code snippet. Any help would be appreciated!

````
 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ("UPDATE studentid.sinfoafter SET username = ?, password = ?, snumber# = ?, fullname = ?, email = ?, phone# = ?, status = ? WHERE username = ?");
            pstmt.setString (1, selected.getUsername ());
            pstmt.setString (2, selected.getPassword ());
            pstmt.setInt (3, selected.getsId ());
            pstmt.setString (4, selected.getFullName ());
            pstmt.setString (5, selected.getEmail ());
            pstmt.setInt (6, selected.getPhone ());
            pstmt.setInt (7, selected.getStatus ());
            pstmt.setString (8, selected.getUsername ());
            pstmt.executeUpdate ();
            conn.close ();```
````

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about fields that end with `#` like `snumber#`, that can be a cause. Could you please try to escape them, like using `snumber#` in mysql?

Comment: Does the table on your SQL server have all the required columns? Also, try to print the statement to see if it's being built correctly.

Comment: @MikhailKopylov Hi, i have added surrounding backticks ` for fields that end with # and ran my program again, this time, there were no exceptions but the sql database does not update still...weird. I will try to print out the statement like @PauMAVA said

Comment: @PauMAVA Hi, I have printed out the built string and executed it using Statement method st.executeUpdate (sql). I printed out the sql statement to see how it was built and it shows this: 
UPDATE studentid.sinfoafter SET username = exampleUsername, password = jPasswordField1, snumber = 101, fullname = exampleName, email = exampleEmail, phone = 12345678, status = 1 WHERE username = exampleUsername
Now the error shows:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'exampleUsername' in 'where clause'. 
exampleUsername is the column data though...

Comment: This happens because you didn't escape the value `exampleUsername` on `... WHERE username = exampleUsername`. Then SQL will try an look for a column called exampleUsername, which does not exist. The solution would be: `... WHERE username = 'exampleUsername'`.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape the value on the `WHERE CLAUSE`:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ("UPDATE studentid.sinfoafter SET username = ?, password = ?, snumber# = ?, fullname = ?, email = ?, phone# = ?, status = ? WHERE username = '?'");
```

If not SQL thinks that you want to fetch all rows where the column `username` has the same value as a non-existing column called `exampleUsername` so it throws a syntax error.